# Has the Minecraft EULA changed since the Microsoft acquisition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Recently, Microsoft acquired Mojang. Did they change the EULA for Minecraft allowing us to use in game cash in our server, etc?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for legal advice.  We are not lawyers; we can't answer this.

Comment: True, but lawyers will say they are not gamers

Comment: They might, true.  But asking us to give you legal advice isn't going to end well for you; "The Internet said I could!" isn't really much of a defense in court.

Comment: For what it's worth, no. You are still not allowed to sell game content. This will not change.

Answer (score 3):

**No**. You are expressely disallowed to sell in-game currency that can affect gameplay in any way. The EULA has expressely disallowed monetization of their game in any form, with only two exceptions, videos and servers with restrictions.

The details of the exception on servers can be found [here](https://mojang.com/2014/06/lets-talk-server-monetisation/). What it boils down to? You are allowed to charge admission, you are allowed to accept donations, you are allowed to sell cosmetic items. You are not allowed to offer anything that impacts gameplay for money.